# Evaluate a rule

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a table like the following:

**RuleStep**

```
StepID | Step Property | Step Condition Id | Step Value | Logical Operator | Next Step Id
```

One of the rows could be the following:
100, Name, 200 (which means equals) , AnyName, 210 (which means And), 300 (points to the next step id).

The above means that I should be evaluating a rule which has a step saying that Name should be equal to AnyName and the next step is chained by operator AND. The next step could be say - age should be equal to 10.

These rules should be evaluated against an object Person with 2 properties Age & Name.I have to verify whether the persons name is AnyName and Age is 10.

Can you please let me know how do I do this? Is there any libraries which can support this? Is there any specific functionality inside C# which can help me?

Thanks,
- Mike

Comment: Are the rules stored in disjunctive (or conjunctive) normal form? If not, how do you deal with rules that mix `And` and `Or` logical operators?

Comment: Leveraging on the LogicalOperator and the next step ID. A step is a standalone rule, and between steps you have a logical operator, which should be used to evaluate the next step.

Comment: Which means you rules build up as `(((((a op b) op c) op d) op e) op f)` where `a`-`f` are each step, and `op`s are the logical operators occurring between them? - which it can be difficult to force every condition you might want to express into such a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) from the [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) package, available via NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any specific functionality inside C# which can help me?

Yes, there is. You can build a [LINQ Expression Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) from the data in your table, [compile it dynamically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356928.aspx) into a function object, and execute the resultant [lambda](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.aspx) against your target object. The library takes a litte time of getting used to, but the constructs that you get a very powerful and extremely fast, so the payback on spending the time to learn it is truly enormous.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty example using reflection:

```
bool CheckEqualityRule (object target, string propertyName, string testValue)
{
    var property = target.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
    var value = (string)property.GetValue(target, null);
    return value == testValue;
}
```